# typescript singleton with dependecy

Tags: javascript, typescript, design-patterns, singleton

I'm building an app, where i'm creating a logger as a singleton,
the problem that i'm facing is that i need to initialise this singleton with data from ENV and i can only do it in a specific place of my code.

Maybe it's not really a singleton since it's returning a different type.

Is it okay to use it like this ? if not do you have any recommandations ?

Thank you.

```js
import CustomLogger, from "./logger"
import ICustomLogger from "./Ilogger"
type LoggerConfig={level:string,format:'json'|'raw'}
class Logger{
    private static logger:ICustomLogger;
    private static config: LoggerConfig

    public static init(config:LoggerConfig){
        this.config = config
    }
    public getInstance():ICustomLogger{
        if(!Logger.config){
            throw new Error('Config not defined')
        }
        if(!Logger.logger){
            Logger.logger = new CustomLogger(config)
        }
        return Logger.logger
    }

}
```

Comment: This isn't a singleton is it? You could make as many new Logger objects as you want.

Comment: Usually I just write export const logger = new Logger() and use the JS module to create the singleton behavior.

Comment: Or use one of the many tried and true java singleton patterns.